# Rename table alias & CTE in VS Code

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code

Is there a plugin to rename those? I tried <kbd>F2</kbd> to no avail.

Comment: For that kind of thing, I usually do a regex find/replace. Do you think that might be an option?